# Play a video file in iPhone 4.1

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4

I am working with sdk 4.1 and i was trying to play a mp4 file but when i tried to play that file all i could do is get the audio started but alas no video.

So how to do that in the latest sdk 4.1

here's the error that i get in my log

```
Error getting audio input device sample rate: '!obj'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem in the past. Some mp4 files are not properly encoded and do not work on the iPad, and you might only hear the soundtrack. Try converting your video to an m4v format, if possible using an H.264 encoding, for example using Handbrake.